# MySQL Join and performance

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Assume this table: `posts_groups`

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| post_id | group_id | type   |    
+---------+----------+--------+
| 1       | 1        | public |    // group #1 sees post #1 where type is public
+---------+----------+--------+
```

And table: `posts`

```
+----+--------+
| id | type   |    
+----+--------+
| 1  | public |  // example : post #1 is public
+----+--------+
```

**Query1**

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts_groups pg
JOIN posts p ON p.id = pg.post_id
WHERE group_id = 1 AND pg.type = public
```

Well, this check group is 1 and `type` ***FROM CURRENT table***, then select some post_id.

**Query2**

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts_groups pg 
JOIN posts p ON p.id = pg.post_id
WHERE group_id = 1 AND p.type = public
```

this query is also doing the same. but checking `type` ***FROM POSTS table***.

But which method is faster and has better performance. any idea how these two queries work.

**CONDITIONS PROCESS!**

in query 1, it says if ( group_id = 1 AND p.type = public ) **THEN** if ( post.id = posts_groups.id ) JOIN posts

in query 2, it says if ( group_id = 1 ) **THEN** if ( post.id = posts_groups.id ) **THEN** if ( posts.type = public ) JOIN posts.

query2's process is a bit longer. or maybe my logic is wrong !!!

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see what optimizer wants to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

there is no difference in two queries , Just go ahead and try and use the one you like.

EDIT: as you edited your question.

They are joind before the WHERE clause , so no difference. to take condition from first or second table , because they joined first.

Comment: I edited my post, the question is something else Mr echo_Me. thanks.

Comment: i updated posts. please take a look at it. :) thanks

Comment: @Pars dude , they are joind before the WHERE clause , so no difference. to take condition from first or second table , because they joined first.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there could be a difference.

Of course logically the WHERE is processed **after** the JOIN, but most optimizers will apply the WHERE-condition before/during the join. If the type column is indexed the plan might change, so you should compare plans as echo-Me already wrote.

If both type columns should be *public*, you might help the optimizer by adding an addtional condition:

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts_groups pg
JOIN posts p ON p.id = pg.post_id
WHERE group_id = 1 AND pg.type = public 
AND p.type = public
```

or

```
SELECT post_id FROM posts_groups pg
JOIN posts p ON p.id = pg.post_id
AND pg.type = p.type
WHERE group_id = 1 AND pg.type = public
```